# How? (.htaccess redirect 301)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a site in localhost/gallery/ folder. I want to make this:
- when I write localhost/gallery/12 real addres whic is open to be localhost/gallery/index.php?url=12
I tried to made it but unfortunately it doesn't work. Return error 310 (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS).

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.(php|html)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html)$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/gallery/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Could you please let me know if the solution I have posted has solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The following line actually forces an EXTERNAL redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/gallery/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So that a request to `http://localhost/foobar` will result in a 301 response telling the client to request `http://localhost/gallery/foobar`.  The client now *makes a new request* to `http://localhost/gallery/foobar`, which will now result in a 301 response to `http://localhost/gallery/gallery/foobar`, and so on.

Try this instead:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.(php|html)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html)$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/gallery/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/gallery/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^.]+)/?$ gallery/index.php?url=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Note that I've added a rewrite condition before your infinitely-looping rule to stop URLs that already begin with /gallery from activating that redirection.

Also, I've amended the file rule to properly rewrite `http://localhost/gallery/foobar` to `http://localhost/gallery/index.php?url=foobar` as you described.  Note that the `/?` in this pattern gives you an optional trailing slash, so that `http://localhost/gallery/12` and `http://localhost/gallery/12/` both work.  If you don't want the latter, remove the `/?` from the pattern.